# Accessing nested Json settings from an Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, environment-variables, azure-functions, connection-string

I have an Azure function, from which I'm reading values from a Json (local.settings.json) config file that looks like this:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlConnectionString": "Server=..."
  },

  "OtherSettings": {
    "MyData": "DataHere"
  }
```

Inside my Azure function, I'm reading the connection string like this:

```
string connectionString = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"ConnectionStrings:SqlConnectionString", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

This works fine. However, if I try the same technique for any other setting, it doesn't work. For example:

```
string myData = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"OtherSettings:MyData", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

just returns null. Please can someone tell me why this works for connection strings, but for no other setting. Also, what's the way around this (I need the code to pick up the overridden parameters once the function is deployed)?

EDIT:

I'm aware that if the local.settings.json has all the settings in a `Values` node it works fine. My question relates to nested settings.

Comment: Take a look hope it will resolved your problem. Let me know if you have any more concern.

Comment: Do you have any more concern? Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot get `OtherSettings` like this by `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`. You should try following way.

***Your Function Signature:***

Add new parameter on your function as **`ExecutionContext context`** just after **`ILogger log`**. Your function should looks like below:

```cs
        [FunctionName("CuriousDevJsonSettingsFunction")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        }
```

***Configuration Builder On Function Body:***

Set below code on your function body. Which will fetch all of your `local.settings.json` property.

```cs
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
   .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
   .AddEnvironmentVariables()
   .Build();
```

***Retrive Your local.settings.json Property From Function:***

It will exactly retrieve your property and its value which you have defined on your `settings.json` file.

```cs
 var otherSettings = new OtherSettings();
 config.Bind("OtherSettings", otherSettings);
```

***Finally Function Should Look Like:***

```cs
public static class CuriousDevJsonSettingsFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("CuriousDevJsonSettingsFunction")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            //Configuration Settings
              var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
             .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddEnvironmentVariables()
             .Build();

            //Access local.settings.json file 
            var otherSettings = new OtherSettings();
            config.Bind("OtherSettings", otherSettings);

            return new OkObjectResult(otherSettings.MyData);
        }
    }
```

***Class I have Used:***

```cs
  public class OtherSettings
    {
        public string MyData { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** This is how you could retrieve your  `local.settings.json` property value from your function. For more details you could take a look at [this docs](https://www.tomfaltesek.com/azure-functions-local-settings-json-and-source-control/)

Comment: What effect will .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json"...) have on the published version (since that file won't exist once it's published)?

Comment: No it wouldn't published. It works only for local development. If you wish to impact on published version you should set on [`App settings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings) on azure portal. See [Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings)